# Please explain how Wordpress works with MySQL character set and collation at a low level

Tags: database, mysql, options, wp-config, collation

As the question title suggests, I'm looking to understand how Wordpress works with MySQL character sets and collation options. As I will show below, things don't make much sense to me...

I installed Wordpress by following the instructions on their installation page:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

As part of the instructions, I followed their advice for manual creation of the MySQL database on the commandline, namely the commands:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE databasename;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO "wordpressusername"@"hostname"
-> IDENTIFIED BY "password";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> EXIT
```

Further, as instructed, I edited the "wp-config.php" file to use UTF-8 character set:

`define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );`

...and left the collation setting blank:

`define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );`

Here is where the fun starts...

1. If I enter a character that is not part of MySQL UTF-8, but is part of UTF-8 MB4, such as , into a post, it shows up correctly on the rendered page. I would have expected this not to happen, as I haven't set the character set to UTF-8 MB4, but the more restricted UTF-8 (as defined by MySQL of course, not as generally understood).
2. If I investigate the issue in MySQL on the commandline, it gets weirder. If I run `show variables like 'char%';`, I get this response:

   ```
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | Variable_name            | Value                      |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | character_set_client     | utf8                       |
   | character_set_connection | utf8                       |
   | character_set_database   | latin1                     |
   | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
   | character_set_results    | utf8                       |
   | character_set_server     | latin1                     |
   | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
   | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   ```

I would have expected database character set to be UTF-8, not latin1.

2. If I run the command `show variables like 'collation%';`, the output is:

   ```
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   | Variable_name        | Value             |
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   | collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
   | collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
   | collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   ```

That's even stranger, for obvious reasons (wouldn't have expected the default latin1_swedish_ci collation in a UTF-8 database).

3. Finally, if I run `show full columns from mywpdatabase.wp_posts;`, the output lines, where the value is not NULL, show collation to be:

`| post_content_filtered | longtext            | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |`

My question then - how can this be explained? Why is my Wordpress install correctly rendering UTF-8 MB4 characters, when the database is defined as UTF-8 in the config? And why is the database showing in MySQL as latin1, swedish collation, instead of UTF-8? And how come, that despite all this, the individual fields in the table are utf8mb4_unicode_ci? A low-level explanation of the way Wordpress works with MySQL would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two defines in wp-config.php of WordPress website:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

> There are several things which are most commonly misunderstood. Names
>   of constants in those defines, might suggest that they are related to
>   the database itself. They are not. They are related to tables within
>   the database.
>
> Database creation is totally independent from table creation.
>   WordPress does not create a database and does not care about
>   database's default character set and collation, as long as it can
>   connect to the database.
>
> The value 'utf8' in the first define means, the least restricted
>   character set from 'utf8' family, which is either 'utf8' or 'utf8mb4'.

If you leave defines above unchanged, before an attempt to install your website, it is like telling WordPress to make its own choices, regarding database's tables character set and collation, which are supported by MySQL ( depending of MySQL version ) and are least limiting.

The following are the things, WordPress analyses to determine its choices, during installation:

- MySQL's version
- database's collation ( in wp-config.php )

Based on MySQL's version, WordPress decides, which group of **utf8** family to use. There are two, distinguished by their names: **utf8** and **utf8mb4**. Character sets from **utf8** group, allow storing of a maximum 3-bytes long characters. Character sets from **utf8mb4** group, allow storing of a maximum 4-bytes long characters.

Now, WordPress checks the value of **DB_COLLATE** define. If empty, it will use the least limiting collation from chosen **utf8** family, otherwise, will use the value specified.

#### Examples

> ```
> define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
> define('DB_COLLATE', '');
> ```
>
> If MySQL does not support **utf8mb4** ( older versions ) then tables
>   character set will be **utf8** and collation will be
>   **utf8_general_ci**. Otherwise, we can expect **utf8mb4** and **utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci**, or **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** ( MySQL version dependent ), respectively.
>
> ```
> define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
> define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_polish_ci');
> ```
>
> Older MySQL version - **utf8** and **utf8_polish_ci**. Newer MySQL
>   version - **utf8mb4** and **utf8mb4_polish_ci** ( **_polish_ci**
>   suffix is honoured )
>
> ```
> define('DB_CHARSET', 'cp1250');
> define('DB_COLLATE', 'cp1250_polish_ci');
> ```
>
> Any MySQL version - **cp1250** and **cp1250_polish_ci**.
>
> ```
> define('DB_CHARSET', 'cp1250');
> define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
> ```
>
> Any MySQL version - error ( mismatch of character set and collation )

#### Summary

In most cases, leaving values of defines, explained above, unchanged, is a good choice. But, if you want tables collation to match the language of your website, you can modify the value of **DB_COLLATE** define, appropriately ( for example - **utf8mb4_polish_ci** ).

**Note:** that explains, why the character  was stored and retrieved properly. Simply, your tables character set belonged to **utf8mb4** group, not **utf8**.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how Wordpress sets collation, but you haven't addressed the rest of the points. Why, if UTF-8 character set is defined, is MySQL showing the database as being latin1? And why is it showing database collation as swedish? In addition, you seem to be confusing character set and collation. Collation only defines ordering, comparison rules, not the character set. Therefore, no matter what collation is used, if UTF-8 is the character set, characters outside it (as defined in the narrower MySQL sense) should not render.

Comment: I'll update my answer, to explain more clearly the process.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've accepted your answer, it's all clear now. The issue is with MySQL and my lack of expertise in it - I didn't know tables can use a broader character set than the database itself. This new info has set my mind at ease. I don't need to change the default character set in MySQL, Wordpress takes care of it at table level.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that it helped.